# Breadth level based partitioning approach for arrays of integers

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, partitioning, partition

I want to partition an initial array (`dF`) and iteratively do the same for the obtained partitions based on a Breadth level approach.
Starting from an initial array (`dF`) two arrays are obtained if a certain condition is met on the two arrays (see `partition_array_(dF, intIter, listMed)` below; that generates 2 arrays of ints) and the process is repeated for each obtained partition (Breadth level wise) up until that inner condition is no longer met then i want to return the last level of obtained partitions.

The partitioning is done according to a value `int` that is iteratively chosen from another array of ints `intIter`. My iterative method goes like the following:

```
 public ArrayList<List<Integer>> partition_rec(List<Integer> dF, Iterator<Integer> intIter, List<Integer> listMed) {
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> partitions_ = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> partitions_bf  =  new ArrayList<>();
       
        
        partitions_.add(dF);
        while ( partitions_.size()!=0) {
            
            partitions_bf  =  new ArrayList<>(partitions_);

            for (int j=0;j< partitions_.size();j++) {
                List<Integer> dss = partitions_bf .get(j);
                numberPartsBf = partitions_bf .size();
                if (intIter.hasNext())
                currentInt  = intIter.next();
                else intIter = listMed.iterator();
                partitions_bf .addAll(partition_array_(dss, currentInt , listMed));
                numberPartsAf = partitions_bf .size();
                if (numberPartsAf > numberPartsBf && partitions_bf .contains(dss)) partitions_bf .remove(dss);
                if (j == partitions_.size()-1){
                 if (partitions_.size() == partitions_bf.size()) return partitions_bf;
                   partitions_ =  new ArrayList<>(partitions_bf );
                    break;
                  
                    }
                   
                else if (!intIter.hasNext()) intIter = listMed.iterator();

            }
        }

        return partitions_bf ;
    }
```

**1.** I want this algorithm to return only the last level children partitions (the smallest arrays obtained by the last for loop).

**2.** make sure this algorithm stops when no new partitions could
be obtained.

I want to make sure its logic is correct.

Other question: Is there any algorithmic optimization to do here for a more compact code ?

**Input**: *List* : [1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11];
*ListMed* ArrayList: [6,3,9]
*intIter* being one of the listMed iterated values.

**Output** ArrayLists: [1,2], [4,5], [7,8], [10,11]

driver code :

```
          List<Integer> dF = {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11};
          List<Integer> listMed = {6,3,9};
          Iterator<Integer> its = listMed.iterator();
          ArrayList<List<Integer>> res = partition_rec( dF,  intIter,  listMed);
```

Comment: When `partition_array_(dss, currentInt, listMed)` cannot partition `dss` it returns an empty list?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (i am controlling the size of `partitions_` and if `dss` cannot be partitioned the list `partitions_` will remain the same)

Comment: When I run the algorithm with the driver code it crashes because in the first line of the `for` loop you want to take the first element (`get(0)`) because the last element that has been partitioned is removed. So it's always the first element that is the next to partition. Did I get it right?

Comment: When I fixed the issue with `List<Integer> dss = partitions_bf .get(j);` the algorithm still crashes because when it exits the `for` loop, `partitions_` is not empty but `intIter` has been consumed and then `currentInt  = intIter.next();` throws. If I replace the `while` condition with `while (partitions_.size() != 0 && intIter.hasNext())` then the code yields the expected result

Comment: yes i check `intIter.hasNext()` as in the second loop OK.  for your first comment: yes i remove the element that has been partitioned because at the end i want the smallest partitioned parts only. Is there still other problems ?

Comment: I believe there is also an issue in the `for` loop when `intIter` has been consumed: it is reset as a new iterator but `currentInt` is not updated

Comment: Functional question: what's the point of reiterating over `listMed`? Suppose you have this list: {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}. Once it has been partitioned with 6 it yields two partitions: {1,2,4,5} where all elements are smaller than 6 and {7,8,10,11} where all elements are bigger than 6, hence 6 can never be used again to partition them

Comment: there's no point indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code is equivalent and more compact with a recursive breadth-first algorithm. It stops when no more partition can be done:

```java
    public static List<List<Integer>> partition_rec(List<Integer> dF, Iterator<Integer> medIter, List<Integer> listMed) {
        List<List<Integer>> toPartition = new LinkedList<>();
        toPartition.add(dF);
        return recursion(toPartition, medIter, listMed, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> recursion(List<List<Integer>> toPartition, Iterator<Integer> medIter, List<Integer> listMed, List<List<Integer>> noMorePartitionable) {
        if (toPartition.isEmpty()) return noMorePartitionable;
        medIter = reiterateIfNeeded(medIter, listMed);
        List<Integer> toPartitionHead = toPartition.remove(0);
        List<List<Integer>> partitions = partition_array_(toPartitionHead, medIter.next(), listMed);
        if(partitions.isEmpty()) noMorePartitionable.add(toPartitionHead);
        toPartition.addAll(partitions);
        return recursion(toPartition, medIter, listMed, noMorePartitionable);
    }

    private static Iterator<Integer> reiterateIfNeeded(Iterator<Integer> medIter, List<Integer> listMed) {
        return medIter.hasNext() ? medIter : listMed.iterator();
    }
```

The lists to partition are stored into `toPartition`. When they are no more partitionable they are accumulated in `noMorePartitionable`. Once `toPartition` is empty, `noMorePartitionable` is returned.

Comment: i want to return all last level obtained partitions (that's when the algo stops: when no other partitioning could be done: not when all meds have been consumed)

Comment: @singhraj what is the expected behavior when all meds are consumed? For instance, if meds={6,3,9} the algorithm should use 6,3,9,6,...?

Comment: yes it should return to the initial value (6 in the example). THe algo stops when `partition_array_` couldn't yield other children for the current parent arrays

Comment: i can't see the stopping condition in your code mine it was at : `if (j == partitions_.size()-1){
                 if (partitions_.size() == partitions_bf.size()) return partitions_bf;
                   partitions_ =  new ArrayList<>(partitions_bf );
                    break;
                  
                    }`

Comment: The exit condition was `if (!medIter.hasNext()) return queue;` But let me edit the code to reiterate over `listMed`. The exit condition is now `if(partitions.isEmpty()) return queue;`

Comment: OK but does your code return only the last partitions and not the the ones that led to those ?

Comment: Yes only the last paritions. The last partitioned element is removed from the queue (`queue.remove(0);`)

Comment: in the case where for the first iteration there's a partitioning (step leading to 2 partitions) then no other partitions could be yielded i see that queue won't contain the 2 mentioned partitons

Comment: @singhraj I'm sorry but I don't understand what leads you to this conclusion. If a partition is successful it is indeed added to the queue (`queue.addAll(partitions);`). I just ran the driver code with `dF = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11}` and `listMed = {6}` and got `[[1, 2, 4, 5], [7, 8, 10, 11]]`

Comment: If a partition is successful it is indeed added to the queue (queue.addAll(partitions);) but then you do `queue.remove(0);` and then in the recursive call no other partitions are added and return queue if `partitions.isEmpty()`

Comment: `queue.remove(0);` is invoked only when `partition_array_(queue.get(0),...)` returned non-empty partitions. So the head of the queue was successfully partitioned and can be safely removed since the partitions were added to the end of the queue. Can you provide an example where the result is unexpected?

Comment: you are exiting with `queue` only if one partition didn't yield any other partition, while my algorithm stops when the two obtained partitions won't yield any more partitions...

Comment: Ok so this example: `dF={1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11}` and `listMed = {6,0,9}` should yield `[[1, 2, 4, 5], [7, 8], [10, 11]]` did I get it right?

Comment: yes absolutely, that is right.

Comment: Ok let me edit my code again, taking this into account